# Checking if a 800million entry hashmap contains an element

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a hashmap containing ~800 million entries (strings)  inside it. It is actually serialized into a file that I have already into a hashmap.

Now I have another huge list of strings which is around ~35million in size. I need to read these 35million strings one by one and format them in a particular manner that is a separate method by itself (it is a very light processing).

Then I need to check if the result of the formatting done on one string from the list is already present in the hashMap or not.

What is the most efficient way to do this in Java?

Comment: It's not Java, but I'd push them into a DB, and would do a JOIN on that... 80 milliion lines is not even near impossible with any serious RDBMS nowadays. I'd suggest Postgres.

Comment: the title says 800 million, but the body says 80 million. Which is correct?

Comment: Also, what are the elements? `int`s? `long`s? Something else?

Comment: The most efficient way to do this in java is to put your data in a database (perhaps MySQL) and access it using JDBC.

Comment: I am surprised at all these suggestions towards a database. Since the data is already stored in a hash map, database (with indexing) would not provide much benefits (Especially if this is a one off task). 35 million is not a lot. You should be able to store all the hashes in memory. Now, for each element in first set check if it is in second set. If you can fit 80 million hashes in memory, it is even better.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Looks like I needed to add more details. I have edited the question now. Looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a Bloom filter which is

> a space-efficient probabilistic data structure that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive retrieval results are possible, but false negatives are not; i.e. a query returns either "inside set (may be wrong)" or "definitely not in set".

(Quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter))

Google Guava provides [an implementation in java](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/HashingExplained#BloomFilter).

Comment: I don't think bloom filter would work for this case. First, bloom filter does not provide exact answer. Second 80/35 millions is a lot to encode in bloom filter (filter size needs to be also in millions to have any practical advantage.

Comment: @ElKamina: I guess the OP will be able to decide if he can deal with a small percentage of false positives, this was just an idea. I haven't experiment a lot with the performace of the Guava implementation, but it seems that people do use it with millions of insertions, and the class has been improved a lot in an earlier release, see https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=892

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by improving the way the hashing function is developed if you **must** have it in-memory. Good resources to help with that can be found in an [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-hashing) by dzone

A step further than that would be to use another [implementation](http://xxl.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/v2/xxl/core/collections/BinarySearchTreeMap.html) of the Map interface, if you don't care about the probable latency introduced with maintaining a sorted structure

Answer (score 1):

If your large dataset is already in a hash table that you're deserializing from disk and you can't change that, then I doubt you're going to do a lot better than just doing the obvious thing and checking the hash table directly. Any transformation of the large hash table into another format is likely to be more expensive than just doing all the lookups one at a time on the table as-is. (~35 million constant-time operations versus at least 800 million + 35 million constant time operations with another constant that's probably not much better, possibly more depending on the new format you want to use.)

If the table where your large dataset is stored is already thread-safe and the computer on which you're running the program has multiple cores, you might get a speedup by running a single lookup thread per core, but even that may not speed things up (or may in fact slow things down) because of coordination overhead and the fact that each individual operation is pretty cheap.

Do you have any ability to change the way the large dataset is prepared? For instance, rather than writing it out as a hash set, could you write it as something else? Can you change the default hash function, and do you know anything about the properties of the strings you're hashing that could be used to build a cheaper hash function? Will they come in a particular order in the input file? These sorts of things could potentially be used to make a faster lookup, but substantial speedups over the naive method are probably going to rely on knowing more about the specific details of your problem.